# Azure function doesn't timeouts earlier than set value

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-functions

I have seen that Azure Functions increased timeout to 10 minutes while default is still 5 minutes.

My `host.json` is

```
{
  "queues": {
  "maxPollingInterval": 2000,
  "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
  "batchSize": 16,
  "maxDequeueCount": 3,
  "newBatchThreshold": 8,
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
 }
}
```

I can see the timeout value as 10 minutes in portal as well, although it didn't pick it up from the host.json I have in my local Visual Studio so I set it manually in the portal.

However, any job that passes 5 minutes is timing out. I couldn't seem to find any information around is apart from that it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`functionTimeout` property should be on top level, not under `queues`:

```json
{
  "queues": {
    "maxPollingInterval": 2000,
    "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
    "batchSize": 16,
    "maxDequeueCount": 3,
    "newBatchThreshold": 8
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```